# sbt displays the logs only for failing tests

Tags: sbt

Is it possible to configure SBT so that only the logs for failing tests are displayed to the console?

It'd avoid to have too much information in general in the output and to be able to concentrate on failing tests.

Comment: This is probably specific to the test framework you're using.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think sbt already manipulates the log during test execution in parallel to show them in sequential block.

So I think it should be do-able in sbt, and it'd a great feature.